# Create relationships between addreses and users. Return it on the view on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.6

I'm having some problems trying to return a view with the user address.
I don't know if the real problem is in my controller or in my models. I'd like to know the correct way to return a user with his address creating a relationship with the models.

**Address Model**

```
<?php

      namespace App;

      use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

      class Address extends Model {

       protected $fillable = ['name','last_name','street_address','street_address2', 'country', 'city', 'state-province', 'phone-number', 'phone-number2', 'address-type'];

     public function user() {
     return $this->hasOne('App\User');
  }
}
```

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

    public function address() {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Address');
    }
 }
```

In the UserController, I'm using the method getAddress, but I really don't know how to get the user address and how to create a user with that relation.

**UserController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use App\Address;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
public function userProfile() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}

public function userAccount(User $user) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    return view('user.account', compact('user'));
}

public function nameUpdate(User $user)
{ 
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255'
    ]);

    $user->first_name = request('first_name');
    $user->last_name = request('last_name');

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function emailUpdate(User $user)
{ 
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    ]);

    $user->email = request('email');

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function passwordUpdate(User $user) {
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
    ]);

    $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}

public function getAddress() {
    $user=Auth::user();
    $adress = $user->adress; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You have got a typo in `$user->adress`.

Comment: I corrected it, but after that, how can I bring the user and the address of the user to my view?

Comment: You can access Auth facade in views directly, so just use that: `{{ Auth::user()->address }}`

Comment: I'm gonna try it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must reverse the relationship so that the address belongs to the user. If a user can have multiple addresses then a user cannot belong to each of those addresses. The addresses must belong to the user.

In the address table you will need a user_id column to start with.

User.php

```
 public function addresses()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
 }
```

Address.php

```
 public function user()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
 }
```

Then you can simply get all the addresses like so:

```
 foreach(Auth::user()->addresses as $address){
      //You can now access your address here
 }
```

Your current controller:

```
 public function getAddresses() {
     $user = Auth::user();
     $addresses = $user->addresses; 
     return $addresses;
 }
```

In a blade file you could do something like:

```
     @foreach(Auth::user()->addresses as $address){
        <li>{{ $address->column_name }}</li>    
     }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But what do I have to do it if I want to have many addresses for a user? And I don't want to get the addresses of all the users. I just want the addresses of the Auth::user()

Comment: You need to edit your question to say that a user can have many addresses. I will edit my answer

Comment: Ok, sorry. Another question, it's just that I'm a noob on this, how could I do this on the UserController. Which is the correct way to do the method for calling the user and the addresses of the user?

Comment: What I've just answered gives you an example of inside a controller and inside a blade template.

Comment: Does the user_id must be a string or an integer?

Comment: Integer, you should read the laravel documentation in regards to relationships if you're asking such questions. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships